# Python syntax error in email address extraction script

Tags: python, windows, email, syntax

I found this python script at [metafilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/39605/How-to-get-email-addresses-out-of-a-sent-mail-folder) and modified the addresses and pass as needed, but I get a script error at the very last line. In the error the little carat symbol is underneath the quote after print "\n

Not being a coder at all, I have no idea where to turn next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I actually want to do is pull out the "From" addresses and not to and CC, but I figured I would get this working properly first.

Script was run in Windows using Python 3.2 and redirected output to a text file.

```
import email
import getpass
import imaplib

HOST = "mail.-----.com"
USER = "sales@-----.com"
FOLDER = "Folder"

connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(HOST)
res, data = connection.login(USER, getpass.getpass())
assert res == "OK"

res, count = connection.select(FOLDER)
assert res == "OK"

res, (msg_nums,) = connection.search(None, "ALL")
assert res == "OK"

for msg_num in msg_nums.split():
    res, message_text = connection.fetch(msg_num, "(RFC822)")
    assert res == "OK"

    message = email.message_from_string(message_text[0][1])
    tos = message.get_all("From") or []
    ccs = message.get_all("Cc") or []
    all_recipients = email.Utils.getaddresses(tos + ccs)
    print "\n".join(addr.lower() for realname, addr in all_recipients)
```

Answer (score 3):

`print` is a function in Python 3, so it needs to be:

```
print("\n".join(addr.lower() for realname, addr in all_recipients))
```

The script was probably originally written for use with Python 2.x.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed it was written in 2006, so I tried several different versions with different errors. Now after making this change and running it with python 32 again, I get:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "email2.py", line 14, in <module>
        assert res == "OK"
    AssertionError

Comment: Sounds like it's not getting the desired response from the mail server. I can't really help debug it beyond that, I'm afraid.